# Webbrowser Scrollto gets NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

i try to open a html page in Webbrowser. This works fine with:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://examplepage.com");
```

But then i want to autoscroll to user defined coordinates (x, y). I think this must be:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 10);
```

If i start the programm i get following error message:

> NullReferenceException was not handled Object reference not set to an object instance

Here is the complete code:

```
namespace Blitzer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.examplepage.com");
            webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The webbrowser navigates asynchronously, so if you try to access the document right after starting the navigation, it won't be loaded yet.

Try creating a [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler and scrolling there:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new      System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.examplepage.com");

    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 10);
    }
```